# rpy2: How to properly convert NaN to NA from panda.DataFrame to R?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, rpy2

I'm trying to pass dataframe from python to R using rpy2 library. I've tried the following method but failed.

- do not do anything - obviously it is NaN in python and result in run
  time error.
- fillna('NA') - it is character instead of NA when interpreted by R.
- fillna(robjects.NA_Logical) - NaN will be turn to 0 instead and no
  imputation will be done.
- fillna(robjects.NA_real) - remain as NaN and result in run
  time error.
- converting it to r dataframe before passing into the method using pandas2ri.py2ri() - same run time error.

```
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pcaMethods = importr('pcaMethods')
pandas2ri.activate()

train_df = pd.read_csv('C:\\misc\\train.csv')
train_dfNA = train_df.fillna(robjects.NA_Real)
result = pcaMethods.pca(train_dfNA, method="svd", nPcs=2)
```

I wish to do conversion and any other stuff in python while R is only used for executing the methods I need (rarely but still needed). Alternatively I know I can just send R codes through `robjects.r` to perform the task but that is another topic of discussion.

Edit: The error I get is the following

```
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in (function (object, method, nPcs = 2, scale = c("none", "pareto",  : Invalid data format.Run checkData(data, verbose=TRUE) for details
```

Comment: Where are you converting Pandas data frame to R data frame? Why are you attempting to fill R NAs inside a Pandas data frame? A simple conversion should translate Python's `NaN` to R's `NA`: `r_dataframe = pandas2ri.py2ri(pandas_dataframe)`.

Comment: I'm passing in the pandas dataframe for missing value imputation. It will be converted in R automatically when `pandas2ri.activate()` as I know, the only problem is how I can let the empty values(NaN) be NAs in R. Forget to mention I've actually tried converting it using `py2ri()` but still facing the same error.

Comment: No where in your code are you converting Pandas dataframe to an R data frame. The `.activate()` simple initializes the converter. Once again, convert *before* calling `pcaMethods` and do not run any `fillna` attempt.

Comment: this is not all the code i've tried, just part of it as an example. I've just tried doing `pandas2ri.py2ri(train_df)` without `fillna` at all and resulted in same error as missing value is still NaN when passing to pcaMethods.

Comment: So NAs work but not NANs? In other words, if you only use R (not Python) to read exact csv file that contain `NA` values, and call `pcaMethods` does any R error occur?

Comment: If directly reading the csv using R won't have any issue. The alternative I'm using  is to read the csv on R through passing strings of R code using `robject.r`.

Answer (score 0):

In R, different "NA" values are defined for different array types. Type casting, and the type hierarchy, make it "just work" when ones does something like `array[i] <- NA`.

Here are some of the NA values in R and how they are mapped in `rpy2`:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
print('%12s   %12s   %20s' % ('rpy2 name', 'R', 'rpy2 type'))
for s in ('NA_Character', 'NA_Real', 'NA_Integer', 'NA_Logical'): 
    r = getattr(ro, s) 
    print('%12s   %12s   %20s' % (s, r, r.typeof if hasattr(r, 'typeof')
                                  else 'Native Python object'))
```

You should get something like:

```
rpy2 name      R                rpy2 type                                                                           
NA_Character   NA_character_    RTYPES.CHARSXP
NA_Real        NA_real_         Native Python object
NA_Integer     NA_integer_      Native Python object
NA_Logical     NA               Native Python object
```

Here you are using `pandas` to set your NA values though, so the resulting type from calling `fillna()` will be what matters when passed to R.

Regarding the runtime error, you are not sharing it but I suspect that this is the R function called reporting that missing values make a PCA impossible to perform.

Finally, I am seeing from the file paths that you are using `rpy2` on Windows. Unfortunately using `rpy2` on Windows ranges "not supported" to "won't even install" depending on the versions.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get what to pass into `fillna()` so the resulting type will be valid for R. The type I want should be NA_real but I've tried passing in `robjects.NA_real` and it will stay as NaN in the pandas data frame and resulted a runtime error on R side. Regarding the error, I've add in to the question's bottom part. I've figure it out to make it work on windows but am not sure if this is one of the "not supported" feature in windows.

Comment: The rpy2 version you are using is likely outdated (because Windows) and you are facing a conversion bug that is no longer present.

Comment: the version I'm using is 2.9.5 @lgautier

Comment: rpy2-2.9.x was developed before the relatively recent changes in pandas (relative to NA handling) were released. Using the latest rpy2 is probably the only option is wanting to use the latest pandas.